# font AweSome not working on mvc3 solution?

Tags: html, css

I have a solution with multiple mvc3 project and each one has it's own area(Accounting, Treasury, Inventory, Trading, ClickMIS And Contract).Contract Project is the library for solution.
now i want to add font Awesome to my solution, then i add a font Folder to Contract Project.
The Addressing in css file for font is :

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
src: url('/Common/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
src: url('/Common/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix'), format('embedded-   opentype');
src: url('/Common/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'); 
src: url('/Common/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
src: url('/Common/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

but no response i got from the solution. always show me 
`GET /Common/fonts/fontawesomewebfont.svg 404 (Not Found)`
i use content on buildaction for my font. can anyone help me on this?

Comment: local `('/Common/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix')`

Comment: download online `('https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/fonts')` and add to your project

Comment: I check it, it's not answering, but when i place it on root of project it solved, but i want to place in areas folders, thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

download here and add to your project file.
[FontAwesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome)

[fonts](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/fonts)

```
@font-face{
    font-family:FontAwesome;
    src:url(fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot);
    src:url(fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot) format("embedded-opentype"),
        url(fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff) format("woff"),
        url(fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf) format("truetype"),
        url(fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?#fontawesomeregular) format("svg");
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
    font-stretch:normal
}
```